# How to prove that an ideal is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Consider the ring of polynomials $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ and the following ideal:
>   $$I=(xy^3-z^3,x^2y-z^2,x^5z-y^5).$$ I should prove that $I$ is prime, but I don't manage to do it directly.

I recall the definition of prime ideal
$$f g\in I\Rightarrow f\in I \text{ or } g\in I$$
It is also equivalent to prove
$$\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]\big/I\ \text{ domain}.$$

Does anybody have an idea? Maybe $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]\big/I$ is isomorphic to some 'simpler' ring which is clearly a domain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Are you sure ? Note that : $$(xy^3-z^3)-z(x^2y-z^2)=xy^3-zx^2y=(xy)(y^2-zx)$$

Comment: Note that $y^2-zx\in I$ or $xy\in I$. In fact, a Groebner basis for $I$ is $(x,y)$ and $(z^2-xy^2,zx-y^2,x^4-y^3)$.

Comment: Sorry minar but I did not understand why this would contradict that I is prime

Comment: @qwertyuio A Groebner basis for $I$ is $(x^5*z - y^5, x^2*y - z^2, x*y^3 - z^3, x*z^3 - y^2*z^2, y^6 - y*z^4, y^5*z^2 - z^6).$  Use it to check that neither $xy$ nor $y^2-z*x$ are in $I$.

Comment: I don't know what a Groeber basis is. But are you sure $y^2-zx\notin I$?

Comment: @qwertyuio: Any monomial that appear in an element of $I$ is a multiple of a monomial coming from your initial polynomials, i.e., $xy^3$, $z^3$, $x^2y$, $z^2$, $x^5z$ and $y^5$. Note that $y^2$ (or $zx$ btw) is not a multiple of any of those, thus $y^2-zx$ cannot belong to $I$.